# Webpage works in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a basic page with no CSS.  There are no errors in the code as I ran it thru  W3c validator. Page works fine in IE but no Firefox or Chrome. It just show the code instead of the page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #CC9;
     }
   </style>
   </head>

   <body>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
   <p align="center">test</p>
   <p align="center"></p>
   <p align="center"></p>
   <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: How are you serving up the page to the browser? Is it via a server running locally or you're just opening the file from your file system?

Comment: IE works fine but Firefox or chrome still shows the code.  We are using httpserver. The mime type is text/html htm,html,shtml text/css css

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use HTML5 doctype declaration?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #CC9;
 }
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, still show the code. We are using httpserver.  The mime type is text/html  htm,html,shtml  text/css  css